# Error 404 happening to page configured in the Controller (Spring)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring application, I have the follow form, whose action will trigger a method from my controller:

```
<form method="POST" action="cadastra_evento.html">
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" size=20 maxlength=40> <br/>

        <input type="text" name="descricao" placeholder="Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o" size=30 maxlength=100> <br/>

        <h3>Periodo da Data</h3>
        inicio: <input name="data_inicial" placeholder="DD-MM-AAAA" pattern="\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}" /> <br/>
        final: <input name="data_final" placeholder="DD-MM-AAAA" pattern="\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}" /> <br/>

        <h3>Periodo do Hor&aacute;rio</h3>
        inicio: <input name="hora_inicial" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" pattern="\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}" /> <br/>
        final: <input name="hora_final" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" pattern="\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}" /> <br/>

        <input type="text" name="duracao" placeholder="dura&ccedil;&atilde;o" size=20 maxlength=2> Minutos <br/>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
    </form>
```

The method associated to this page is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cadastra_evento", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView cadastra_evento(@RequestParam("nome") String nome, @RequestParam("descricao") String descricao, @RequestParam("data_inicial") String data_inicial, @RequestParam("hora_inicial") String hora_inicial, @RequestParam("data_final") String data_final, @RequestParam("hora_final") String hora_final, @RequestParam("duracao") String duracao)
    {
        if(sessao != null)
        {
            if(sessao.getUsuario().temAutorizacao("cad_evento"))
            {
                Date d_inicio = new Date(Date.parse(data_inicial));
                Date d_final = new Date(Date.parse(data_final));
                Time h_inicio = new Time(Time.parse(hora_inicial));
                Time h_final = new Time(Time.parse(hora_final));
                int duracao2 = Integer.valueOf(duracao).intValue();

                EventoDAO evento = new EventoDAO(nome, descricao, d_inicio, d_final, h_inicio, h_final, duracao2, sessao.getUsuario());
                int saida = evento.cadastra();

                if(saida == 0) 
                {
                    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
                    mav.addObject("message", "Erro ao cadastrar o evento");
                    return mav;
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
                    mav.setViewName("/listagem_evento");
                    return mav;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
                mav.addObject("message", "Usuário sem permissão de acesso");
                return mav;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("/usuario_login_page");
            return mav;
        }
    }
```

What happen is that when I click in the submit button, I receive a error message 404, because the system is trying reach the page /WEB-INF/jsp/cadastra_evento.jsp, that doesn't exist. I have an other page that uses this same scheme, login.htm, triggered by the login page, but that page is working fine.

Someone can find any error in the code above?

PS.: I try use change the name of attribute 'value' of RequestParam to don't match with the name of method (I thought about some sort of conflict), but still don't work).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.html` after your controller request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cadastra_evento.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Or removing `.html` from the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="cadastra_evento">
```

Comment: Nope, this suggestion doen't work too. What is really bothering me is that I have  other page in exactly the same way as that working perfectly, and that doesn't.